# #include issue, " 'foo()' was not declared in this scope"

Tags: c++, glut

Yesterday I wrote a simple program. The problem is that g++ won't compile it -

```
main.cpp: In function ‘void display()’:
main.cpp:32:21: error: ‘loadObj’ was not declared in this scope
  loadObj("model.obj");
```

I don't understand why - everything has been included. I'm trying to build it with this command

```
g++ -Wall -o main objLoader.cpp main.cpp -lGL -lglut -lGLU
```

There is a link to source: [CLICK](https://github.com/dominik-zeglen/CPP/tree/master/GLUT/objLoader)

Any ideas?

Comment: Not much C++ in the linked code.

Comment: @chris is right! It has exactly the same issue as stated in the dupe: `#ifdef __OBJLOADER_H_INCLUDED__`

Comment: By the way, [don't use leading double underscores](http://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/440558) in names.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'd never think that i screwed up guards, so i didn't search any mistake there :)
Anyway thanks for help guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your include guards in ObjLoader.h are wrong.

```
#ifdef __OBJLOADER_H_INCLUDED__
```

should be

```
#ifndef __OBJLOADER_H_INCLUDED__
```

Note the `n` after the `if`. As it currently stands, the contents of the header are always ignored by all source files.

Comment: Oh God, again a single letter ruins a whole day :)
Thank you!

Comment: Long live #pragma once.

Answer (score 1):

try declaring the function with const char*

Comment: Won't help this error, but it's a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Change your safe guards in your `objLoader.h` to:

```
#ifndef __OBJLOADER_H_INCLUDED__
```

`#ifdef` is "if defined" which obviously is not.